# How to get secret key of one user to send to other users in android?

Tags: android, android-keystore, secret-key

Consider user A wants to store some items. It is to be encrypted in app and sent to server. Now user A wants to allow access to those items with user B and user C. User B and user C need key to decrypt it.

I thought of doing this :

*Android key store is used to encrypt data in user A. Key stored in keystore is exported with user authentication. This key is sent to user B and user C with possibly an asymmetric algorithm.*

But I was not able to get key back from key store. Is there a way store the key safely and only be got back with user authentication?

If not possible with keystore, is there any alternative?

Comment: This kind of problem is called key exchange.  There's a variety of ways to solve it, all of them with different weaknesses.  If you were willing to give the key to the server, it would be easy.  But that would allow the server to decrypt it, which makes the point of encrypting it on the server moot.  The way most of the net does it is with public key cryptography (each side has 2 keys, one public and one private).  The problem is with your server in the middle it opens up vulnerabilities if your server isn't trusted.  What attack vectors are you looking to avoid?

Comment: I have no idea about different attack vectors. I wanted to store public key of users in server and private key in device. So when user A wants send key(used to encrypt item) to user b, it would be encrypted with Pkey of user B and same with user C. Is this vulnerable?  But my problem is how do I make sure that key got from user A is secure in device? For that I wanted to store in KeyStore, but I'm not able to get  bytearray of key stored in keystore of user A.

Comment: I thought of one solution today, no idea if it works. That is to store key(used to encrypt item) in database after encrypting it with a key in keystore. When needed to send to other users or to decrypt items, the key in database can be decrypted using key in keystore after user authentication. I have no clue if this is secure.

Comment: There's no need to store the key encrypted in the db.  But if you're using public key encryption and store everyone's public key in the db, the process is:  1)Client A uploads the unencypted file (using SSL so its encrypted in transit)  2)The server encrypts it with Client B's public key.  3)Send the newly encrypted file to client B, do not save the file.  When doing public keys like this, an encrypted file is only good to send to 1 person-  the person who's public key you used.

Comment: The other option is to store the unencrypted item int he db, and encrypt it with whatever public key you need as you need to.